# How to perform incremental training of large data set using (scikit) Adaboost classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, adaboost

I have a large size of the training dataset, so in order to fit it into the **AdaBoost classifier**, I would like to do **incremental training**.

Like in `xgb` we have a parameter called `xgb_model` to use the trained xgb model for further fitting the new data, I am looking for such parameters in AdaBoost classifier.

Currently, I have am trying to use `fit` function to iteratively train the model but it seems my classifier is not using the previous weights. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible out-of-the-box. sklearn supports incremental/online training in some estimators, but not `AdaBoostClassifier`.

The estimators that support incremental training are listed [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#incremental-learning) and have a special method named `partial_fit()`.

Answer (score 0):

see [gaenari](https://github.com/greenfish77/gaenari)
it is c++ incremental decision tree.

support:

- insert(csv), update(), and rebuild().
- report()